# Copiar de una Tabla a otra validando la existencia de los elementos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Debo copiar elementos de una tabla a otra, donde los elementos no coincidan, además deben ser elementos que cumplan algunas condiciones y adicional los vaya insertando con un ID que se incremente automáticamente.

Buscando en la red encontré la instrucción EXCEPT donde el resultado me arroja los elementos que que no se encuentran en la otra tabla, es el siguiente:

```
    SELECT INSTRUMENTO FROM TVECTOR WHERE TIPO_VALOR IN ('B','BI','90','91','92','93','94','95','97','98','D8','F','CD','D2',
            'JI','JE','I','IM','IQ', 'IS','LD')
    EXCEPT
    SELECT EMISION FROM TINSTRUMENTO WHERE TIPO_VALOR IN ('B','BI','90','91','92','93','94','95','97','98','D8','F','CD','D2',
            'JI','JE','I','IM','IQ', 'IS','LD')
```

La condición son que coincidan los elementos en TIPO_VALOR. ¿Cómo puedo mandar el resultado de esa consulta a la tabla destino? Intente algo así pero no me funciona:

```
DECLARE @ID_INSTRUMENTO INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID_INSTRUMENTO),0) + 1 FROM TINSTRUMENTO) --INCREMENTAL AUTOMÁTICO
DECLARE @ID_TIPO INT = 4

    SELECT INSTRUMENTO FROM TVECTOR WHERE TIPO_VALOR IN ('B','BI','90','91','92','93','94','95','97','98','D8','F','CD','D2',
        'JI','JE','I','IM','IQ', 'IS','LD')
    EXCEPT
    SELECT EMISION FROM TINSTRUMENTO WHERE TIPO_VALOR IN ('B','BI','90','91','92','93','94','95','97','98','D8','F','CD','D2',
            'JI','JE','I','IM','IQ', 'IS','LD')

    INSERT INTO TINSTRUMENTO (ID_INSTRUMENTO, ID_TIPO, TIPO_VALOR, SERIE, EMISION)
    SELECT
         @ID_INSTRUMENTO ID_INSTRUMENTO 
        ,@ID_TIPO ID_TIPO
        ,TIPO_VALOR
        ,SERIE
        ,INSTRUMENTO
    FROM TVECTOR
    WHERE TIPO_VALOR IN ('B','BI','90','91','92','93','94','95','97','98','D8','F','CD','D2','JI','JE','I','IM','IQ', 'IS','LD')
```

El error para empezar me sale en el incremental automático, y es el mismo que uso en otros procedimientos, alguien tiene una idea? Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La parte del except, espero que la tengas clara, porque lo que cuentas y lo que dice la select quizá no son lo mismo.

Como después veo que utilizas la tabla TVector, doy por supuesto que si te funciona el except como lo quieres, y que lo has insertado en TVector, cosa que no se ve en el código.

Por tanto en la solución que te planteo, yo tengo un conjunto de datos en TVector, que quiero insertar en TInstrumento.

```
CREATE TABLE TINSTRUMENTO
([ID_INSTRUMENTO] INT, 
 [ID_TIPO]        INT, 
 [TIPO_VALOR]     VARCHAR(2), 
 [SERIE]          VARCHAR(2), 
 [EMISION]        VARCHAR(2)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE TVECTOR
([TIPO_VALOR] VARCHAR(2), 
 [SERIE]      VARCHAR(2), 
 [EMISION]    VARCHAR(2)
);
GO
INSERT INTO TVECTOR 
(TIPO_VALOR, SERIE, EMISION)
VALUES
('B','BI','90'),
('B','BI','93'),
('B','BI','94');
GO
INSERT INTO TINSTRUMENTO (ID_INSTRUMENTO, ID_TIPO, TIPO_VALOR, SERIE,  EMISION)
VALUES
(1,1,'A','BD','84'),
(1,1,'B','BI','93');
GO
```

Ahora con el escenario preparado, voy a insertar en TInstrumento aumentando el max id.

```
DECLARE @ID_INSTRUMENTO INT = (SELECT (ISNULL(MAX(ID_INSTRUMENTO),0)) FROM TINSTRUMENTO);
-- OBSERVA QUE TE HE QUITADO EL MAS 1
DECLARE @ID_TIPO INT = 4;

;WITH CTE AS (
    select *  , ROW_NUMBER () OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ROW
from (
    SELECT    T.TIPO_VALOR
            , T.SERIE
            , T.EMISION

    FROM TVECTOR T
    EXCEPT
    SELECT TIPO_VALOR, SERIE, EMISION
    FROM TINSTRUMENTO 
    ) as Derivada
)
INSERT INTO TINSTRUMENTO (ID_INSTRUMENTO, ID_TIPO,TIPO_VALOR,  SERIE, EMISION)
    SELECT 
           C.ROW+@ID_INSTRUMENTO, -- LA NUMERACION DE FILAS EMPIEZA EN 1
           @ID_TIPO,
           C.TIPO_VALOR,
           C.SERIE,
           C.EMISION
    FROM CTE C;
```

Tienes que tener en cuenta varias cosas. En row_number la ordenación es, la que el motor decida para las filas de tVector.

El código no esta preparado para tener concurrencia.

Te dejo dos enlaces, para que veas como funciona row_number y como funcionan las cte,s.

[Numerar filas (Row_Number())](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/)

[Tablas de expresión común (Cte)](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-1/)

Comment: Gracias Javi, te comento que la parte del EXCEPT es para comprobar que los elementos que están en TINSTRUMENTO no se repitan con los que estan en TVECTOR, es decir pretendo actualizar aquellos cuyo TIPO_VALOR contengan solamente B, BI, 90, etc y que INSTRUMENTO no se repitan en la tabla TINSTRUMENTO. Tu recomendación funciona perfectamente, pero si la genero más de una vez duplica la inserción. Si no es con el EXCEPT también e intentado con un IF NOT EXISTS pero no logro formular la subconsulta correcta.

Comment: Si ya tienes un origen de datos válido (el del excepto) puedes hacer lo siguiente. Mi query dice with CTE as ( .....)insert into. Como ves me he comido la parte interna del CTE. Ahí puedes poner tu query añadiéndole la columna del row mimbre. Sino entonces necesito que me pongas un ejemplo de filas de origen y resultado esperado

Comment: Gracias nuevamente, esta muy interesante el tema. TVECTOR es una tabla que se alimenta diariamente con una rutina programada y TINSTRUMENTO es una tabla el cual contiene un extracto de TVECTOR con solo unos elementos (TIPO_VALOR) que se necesitan para un aplicativo. La intención es comparar TVECTOR contra TINSTRUMENTOS y aquellos elementos condicionados por TIPO_VALOR que no se encuentren en TINSTRUMENTOS insertarlos y no duplicar los que ya existen. La consulta del EXCEPT me arroja: '91_CI350CB_19-13', '91_CI350CB_19-9', '91_CI350CB_20', etc el cual no existen en TINSTRUMENTOS e insertarlos.

Comment: Ahora no estoy delante del ordenador pero así al vuelo' conoces merge?. Busca en mi blog cuanto tengas un rato, que tengo un ejemplo que puede ayudarte. No obstante de noche cuando llegue, intento prepararte algo.

Comment: Ya he modificado la respuesta, como te conté con una tabla derivada dentro del cte como origen de la fuente de datos. Si observas el interior del cte, ahora tenemos un select *, row_number.... from ( ) as derivada, y en el interior de la tabla derivada está el select con el except.. https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/06/tabla-derivada/

Comment: Gracias Javi, lo implemente hoy mismo solo modifique las condiciones del ID_TIPO para que me diera el ID correcto para TIPO_VALOR. Funciona de maravilla